# MYSQL Delete Query based on condtion

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, sql-delete

I have a table **Product** and i have another table **Rating**
I want to delete products that have 3 or more ratings score lower than 3.

Here's what i tried

```
DELETE p  FROM product p 
JOIN rating r ON r.produits_id = p.id  
IN
  (SELECT produits_id 
  FROM rating 
WHERE rating.score < 3
GROUP BY rating.produits_id  
HAVING COUNT(*)  > 2 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the table directly to the query that returns the ids from `rating`:

```
DELETE p  
FROM product p 
JOIN (
  SELECT produits_id 
  FROM rating 
  WHERE score < 3
  GROUP BY produits_id  
  HAVING COUNT(*)  > 2
) r ON r.produits_id = p.id
```

Comment: got this error:

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: @AbdelmlakDhif you have defined produits_id in the table rating as a foreign key to id of product so you can't delete a product with an id that exists in rating in the column produits_id. You should have defined produits_id with ON DELETE CASCADE, so that when a product is deleted then all the rows in the table rating that have that id would also be deleted.

Comment: yessssssssssss !!! thank you im accepting your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `in` in the `where` clause:

```
DELETE p 
    FROM product p 
    WHERE p.id  IN (SELECT r.produits_id 
                    FROM rating r
                    WHERE r.score < 3
                    GROUP BY r.produits_id  
                    HAVING COUNT(*)  >= 3
                   );
```